# LINQ query on List<T> to get List<U> based on minimum value

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, generic-list

I have a `List<UserLoginRecord>` object which consists of three properties.

```
UserID  ID2      LoginTimeStamp
1234567 300009   04/08/2015 18:55:45
1234567 300009   04/08/2015 09:12:32
7654321 300010   14/08/2015 11:55:45
7654321 300010   20/08/2015 13:38:00
```

I want to run Linq query to return only the first record for UserID and UserID2 combination. i.e. the following output

```
UserID  ID2      LoginTimeStamp
1234567 300009   04/08/2015 09:12:32
7654321 300009   14/08/2015 11:55:45
```

I have tried the following which unfortunately doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

```
   var newList = o_userLoginList.GroupBy(gby => new {gby.UserID, gby.ID2})
                .Select(x => new UserLoginRecord
                {
                    UserID = x.UserID,
                    ID2 = x.ID2,
                    LoginTimeStamp = x.Min(LoginTimeStamp),
                });
```

Comment: what is wrong now with your query?

Comment: "doesn't work" provides us with no information, basically. I suspect the problem is just that you need `x.Key.UserID` and `x.Key.ID2`, but it's really important that you express the exact error in the question.

Comment: I get the errors ```Can not resolve symbol x.UserID```, ```Can not resolve symbol x.ID2``` and ```Can not resolve symbol x.LoginTimeStamp``` in the ```Select``` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newList = o_userLoginList.GroupBy(gby => new {gby.UserID, gby.ID2})
                .Select(x => new UserLoginRecord
                {
                    UserID = x.Key.UserID,
                    ID2 = x.Key.ID2,
                    LoginTimeStamp = x.Min(y=>y.LoginTimeStamp),
                });
```